# Converting a quadratic objective function in piecewise linear function

Tags: linear-programming, quadratic-programming

The objective function is of the form:

$max$  $x^2/2+y^2/2+z^2/2$

I would like to convert it to piecewise linear function. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that. What is the intended use? What constraints are there? Are x,y,z continuous?

Comment: If it had been a minimization problem you could use the idea in https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/Mor-LorentzAppr_2001.pdf

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to add constraints like
$2\lambda_x = x^2$
$2\lambda_y = y^2$
$2\lambda_z = z^2$
Then obj =$\lambda_x+\lambda_y+\lambda_z$

Another complicated way is to consider each of the terms $x^2, y^2, z^2$ or may be sum of them $(x^2+y^2 + z^2) \over 2 $ piecewise
Say for $x^2 \over 2$ identify points $(x_i,f_i)$ for $i=1...n$
Introduce constraints
$\sum_i \delta_i x_i = x$
$\sum_i \delta_i f_i = \lambda_x$
$\sum_i \delta_i = 1$
$\delta_i \ge 0$ and $\delta_i$ is special order set type 2 (two adjacent) are $\gt 0$
Then objective same as before replacing $x,y,z$ with $\lambda_x,\lambda_y,\lambda_z$.